# What is redux actually?

Tags: javascript, redux

As i am a beginner on redux and i searched on the web about it. I got the answer as a state container. Even we can maintain the state of the element in the jquery just like the below code

```
if ($('.foobar').hasClass('active')) {
                doSomething();
         }
```

Can anyone tell me what it is actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux is a state container.

You *can* maintain state in the DOM, but this is awful if you have an alternative. Why?

- Harder to test: you need a fake DOM to test *anything*
- Harder to reason about: multiple paths can update that state
- Harder to debug: same reasons
- Harder to maintain: same reasons

Being able to have a single, solid mechanism for mutating state is a huge win across the board. Having known mechanisms for interacting with that state, recording that state, tracking that state, etc. is a huge win.